# Why do classes with fewer words have higher probability?

Tags: classification, naive-bayes-classifier

Given that I have a word that does not occur in any of my documents: `newword`, and given that I have two classes: `class1` and `class2`. For instance, the total number of words in `class1` is 3, the total number of words in `class2` is 6, and the number of unique words in all documents is 8.

Also, given the Naive Bayes formula, the word `newword` will have a higher probability of belonging to `class1` (because the denominator will be lower while the numerator stays the same). Is there any statistical/logical theoretical explanation (that drives the algorithm) about this behavior?

In a nutshell, I just want to know what is the **motivation** of giving higher probability to classes with fewer words.

Ps.: I am using Laplace Smoothing. Therefore:
 P(newword|class1) = 0 + 1 / 3 + 8 = 0.09 >
P(newword|class2) = 0 + 1 / 6 + 8 = 0.07

Answer (score 2):

The Naive Bayes formula doesn't do what you say. For classes $C_k$ and words $x_1, \ldots, x_n$, the formula is

$P(C_k | x_1, \ldots, x_n) \propto P(C_k) \prod_{i=1}^N P(x_i | C_k)$

If the word `newword` doesn't occur, we have no prior information about $P(x_i | C_k)$, so all these conditional probabilities should be equal. So the right-hand side is just proportional to $P(C_k)$, which is independent of the number of words in $C_k$.

Comment: I edited my question :)

Comment: I do not understand why you think the conditional probabilities P(newword|class) are given by these formulas. Since newword doesn't occur in the data, and you haven't given any other prior information, it seems that you actually have no principled way to calculate the conditional probability. I, and I guess most people, would assign equal a priori conditional probabilities, as mentioned in my answer.